# VBS Script not terminating the Excel Application in Task Manager

Tags: excel, vbscript, exit, taskmanager

I have been struggling with what seems to be a common problem regarding opening, running Excel workbook macros, and closing the application from a visual basic script file (.vbs). I cannot terminate the Excel.exe.

I have found a number of recommendations about closing out the objects in the correct order, quitting before setting to nothing, being explicit about each object belonging to the parent object, but I still cannot seem to close of out EXCEL.EXE without manual intervention.

Some mention running a cmd script to kill Excel. I kick off a script like this manually when I have verified it is safe to do so but it is often not. I have dozens of individual batches kicked off each day, and some may be running halfway through during the kick off and completion of another. I would like the .vbs to close its created Excel instance so as to not overrun the memory.

Here is the skeleton of my script:

```
Set Params = Wscript.Arguments ' some arguments used in the run

Set eApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
eApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run happens here for a log start

Set objWorkbook = eApp.Workbooks.Open("...")
eApp.Application.Visible = True
eApp.Windows(1).Visible = True
eApp.Worksheets(1).Activate
eApp.Application.Run "'...'!...", Cstr(Params(0)), Cstr(Params(1))

objWorkbook.Close False
eApp.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Set objWorkbook = Nothing

' CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run happens here for a log complete

eApp.Application.Quit
Set eApp = Nothing
Set Params = Nothing

Wscript.Quit
```

Is there anything that those more experienced can spot with the above code?

Comment: Just the fact you spelled `Application` wrong here: `eApp.Applicaiton.DisplayAlerts = True`. Are you sure there aren't any error messages or dialogs left open in the Excel instance?

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` in your original script to ignore some other errors? It might be masking an error somewhere else.

Comment: Haha apologies - i hand wrote the example and that’s on me- there are no error messages from the process and no masking. The macros run successfully inside excel as well.

Comment: I have determined that when I comment out the `eApp.Application.Run` line it completes with no remaining EXCEL.EXE. I suppose I'll have to debug that macro or maybe throw an `End` statement before the last Exit Sub. Trying to think about what more situations exist to keep the Excel Application running after the macro has completed...